# About the control processing method of the apply application when using the IIDR Event Publishing

Tags: db2, ibm-data-replication

I am considering Db2 replication using IIDR (IBM's DB replication product) 11.4.0.

I am thinking of adopting the event publishing method instead of the Q replication method.

In the Q replication method, if LOAD processing is performed on the source table (the base DB table of replication), it will be detected and as a full refresh process, and the target table (the replication destination DB table) will be all the data will be re-intake.

In the case of the event publishing method, is there a way to detect that the LOAD processing to the source table has been done?

According to the manual, there is a description that a message informing the capture that the capture received the message that the LOAD to the target table is completed is output as a control message, but this control message I don't really understand the role.

In the case of the event publishing method, if anyone knows what kind of control processing should be done for the program that reflects the replication data in the target table, could you tell me?